# insert NULL in sql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build query using two array 1 for column and another for value. I have 3 integer columns in first array for which I don't want to store 0 as default so i want to set NULL, I want to check if any value entered for it, if not entered i want to set NULL for it . 
But when i create query i cant see NULL, i just see null replaced by blank. Seems like PHP is stripping out the NULL word ?

```
$set_null = array("asst_phone","mailing_zip","other_zip");

    foreach($columns as $key=>$col){
    if(in_array($col,$set_null) && $values[$key] == ""){
       $val[$key] = NULL;
    }
    else    
       $val[$key] = "'".$values[$key]."'";
    }
    $query_vals = "";
    foreach($val as $qval){
      if($qval == "") $query_vals .= NULL;
        $query_vals .= $qval;
            }
    echo $query_vals;
```

It generates query like below

```
INSERT INTO zoho_contacts (`contactid`,`smownerid`,`contact_owner`,`lead_source`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`accountid`,`account_name`,`email`,`title`,`department`,`phone`,`home_phone`,`other_phone`,`fax`,`mobile`,`date_of_birth`,`assistant`,`asst_phone`,`reports_to`,`smcreatorid`,`created_by`,`modifiedby`,`modified_by`,`created_time`,`modified_time`,`mailing_street`,`other_street`,`mailing_city`,`other_city`,`mailing_state`,`other_state`,`mailing_zip`,`other_zip`,`mailing_country`,`other_country`,`description`,`email_opt_out`,`skype_id`,`salutation`,`add_to_quickbooks`,`secondary_email`) values ('418176000000052001','418176000000047003','','','','','418176000000047027','','','','','02164 25452132','','','','9798659821','','',,'','418176000000047003','','418176000000047003','','','','','','','','','',,,'','','','','','Mr.','','')
```

My mysql column structure

column properties = NULL => Yes, DEFAULT => NULL, right ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$val[$key] = NULL;
```

with

```
$val[$key] = 'NULL';
```

Comment: MySQL is looking for the string, not a php variable.

Comment: if we enclose NULL with 'NULL' then it works for column with datatype varchar, for integer column it stores zero, which i dont want to.

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me: Does the integer column allow `NULL`?  Or is the column defined in the database as providing a default value of `0` when no value is provided?

Comment: @David yes, I'm going to ask that!

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me: The "resulting query" in the question still shows no instance of `NULL` in the inserted values, which it would need.  What is the resulting query when you try this approach of wrapping `NULL` in quotes?  Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

In php, NULL  needs to be quoted
(if you want it to work in this query)

Comment: if i enclose NULL with 'NULL' then it works for column with datatype varchar, for integer column it stores zero, which i dont want to.

Comment: (regarding this answer) Not true.  In PHP the value NULL is perfectly acceptable unquoted.  The issue is that when inserting NULL into a string, the value gets converted to be a blank string, or ''.  In order to get MySQL to insert a null value, the string value of "NULL" needs to be passed into the query.

Comment: @nageeb : then whats the solution ??

Comment: the solution is to pass 'NULL' into the sql query.  $foo=NULL evaluates to null in php, but if you want to pass that null value into  MySQL, then you need to pass the literal value of 'NULL' so it would have to be $foo = 'NULL'.

Comment: no i tried that.....it stores NULL in varchar column but for integer column it stores 0.

Comment: @nageeb... I was referring to this particular example of feeding it into a query, but I can see why you read it that way

Comment: So what happen when you need to insert a string happened to be NULL, hypothetically?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a better idea to use mysql_escape_string for all values.

```
if($val != "")
$val= "".mysql_escape_string($val)."";
else
$val = "NULL";
```